# Unable to get clustered table definition using bq.py cli

Tags: google-bigquery, google-client

I have a Google BigQuery clustered partition table. And I am trying to get Google BigQuery clustered partition table definition using bq.py cli tool. I get the json output but it does not have clustering information.

```
% bq version  

This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.69


% bq show \   
--schema \
--format=prettyjson \
 uk-kingdom-911:ld_cv_1_population.cv_performance_t1_agg3_auh_mvpart

 
[
  {
    "name": "hstamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
  },
  {
    "name": "account_id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
 ....
.....
]
```

Json output does not have clustering information. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you've used the `--schema` flag. The `--schema` flag only shows the basic schema of the table and nothing else. Remove that flag and you should see everything:

```sh
> bq show --format=prettyjson example_ds.test_table
==========================================================
{
  "clustering": {
    "fields": [
      "second_col"
    ]
  },
  "creationTime": "1623325001027",
  "etag": "xxx",
  "id": "my-project:example_ds.test_table",
  "kind": "bigquery#table",
  "lastModifiedTime": "1623325001112",
  "location": "xxx",
  "numBytes": "0",
  "numLongTermBytes": "0",
  "numRows": "0",
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "first_col",
        "type": "DATE"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "second_col",
        "type": "INTEGER"
      }
    ]
  },
  "selfLink": "xxxx",
  "tableReference": {
    "datasetId": "example_ds",
    "projectId": "my-project",
    "tableId": "test_table"
  },
  "timePartitioning": {
    "type": "DAY"
  },
  "type": "TABLE"
}
```